# Using wirejs with jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, wirejs

I have a jQuery plugin, say 'myPlugin' that I use as follow:

- If my DOM contains:

  ```
  <div id="some-element">Nothing special here</div>
  ```
- I will call my plugin on the div:

  ```
  $('#some-element').myPlugin();
  ```
- It will make the plugin do its things which will result in (for instance):

  ```
  <div id="some-element">Something happened here</div>
  ```

I'm trying to figure out if this plugin can be used somehow as a component in a wirejs spec, like in the example below (except there is no such thing as the onDom I'm using):

```
define({
    myPluginComponent: {
        create: {
            module: 'myPlugin',
            onDom: '#some-element'
        }
    }
});
```

I would imagine some folks already tried to use wirejs with jQuery plugins. Can someone please share an example or some documentation on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plugin follows a similar pattern to jQuery UI widgets, then you could use the 'wire/jquery/ui' plugin.  This plugin accounts for the unique way that jQuery plugins "construct" instances and set/get properties.

From the [docs](https://github.com/cujojs/wire/blob/master/docs/jquery.md#jquery-ui-widgets), I came up with this:

```
define({
    myPluginComponent: {
        widget: {
            type: 'myPlugin',
            node: { $ref: 'dom!some-element' }
        }
    },
    $plugins: ['wire/jquery/ui', 'wire/jquery/dom']
});
```

"myPlugin" is the name of your plugin property on `$.fn`.  If your plugin takes configuration options, you can provide them as an `options` property alongside the `node` property.

Comment: It does follow the same pattern. Thank you for the example!